# Angular 1.x with webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, webpack-2

**Uncaught ReferenceError: myApp is not defined**

I am trying to setup `Webpack` with `Angular 1.x` but getting the above mentioned error. Following is my configuration settings and folder structure. Let me know what I am doing wrong with `Webpack`.

**Folder Structure -**

[image: Folder Structure]

**index.html File -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Directives - Angular</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <first-directive></first-directive>
    <second-directive></second-directive>
    <third-directive></third-directive>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

**first-directive.js**

```
myApp.directive('firstDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: '<h1>This is a first directive</h1>'
    }
})
```

**webpack.config.js file -**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ["./app.js", "./directives/first-directive.js", "./directives/second-directive.js", "./directives/third-directive.js"],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }   
};
```

**Also,** if I am using wildcard like below mentioned, it is also not working.

```
entry: ["./app.js", "./directives/*"]
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong with webpack configuration.

FYI - `bundle.js` looks like this - http://codepad.org/Kd7P5Evy

Comment: Can you show us your `app.js` file?

Comment: @31piy updated the question

Comment: Is that all the content of the files?

Comment: @31piy yes it is all for the time being a single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, the file `first-directive.js` has a variable `myApp`, which seems to be `undefined`.

To correct this, you need either of the following two ways:

**Export the module's definition from `app.js`, and import it in `first-directive.js`**:

```
// app.js
export var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// first-directive.js
import {myApp} from './app';

myApp.directive('firstDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<h1>This is a first directive</h1>'
  }
});
```

**Export directive's definition from `first-directive.js`, and import it in `app.js`:**

```
// first-directive.js
export function firstDirective() {
  return {
    template: '<h1>This is a first directive</h1>'
  };
}

// app.js
import {firstDirective} from './first-directive';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('firstDirective', firstDirective);
```